# How do I get rid of pixel gaps in my textures?

Tags: texturing, texture-painting

Currently, I am trying to do texture painting for my model. However, there are pixel gaps in my texture when I try to paint on the model from the 3D viewport, but not when painting on the UV map directly.

[image: Comparison]

They appear to be pixels on the UV map itself, with consistent pixel sizes. I have tried scaling the model itself, but that did nothing to help. The pixel size seems to be fixed based on the UV and does not change whether I zoom in, out, or paint from different angles. I have tried opening a new file and painting on the default blender cube, but that had no issue. But when I appended the model from the original project to the blank project, the problem returned, making me assume it was a problem with the model.

[image: Close-up]

If it helps with anything, the texture size is 2048x2048.

Any help will be appreciated. Thank you very much in advance.

Edit: Link to the file https://www.mediafire.com/file/y6wwgmei7kst84y/Test.blend/file

Comment: Hello could you please pack your image and share your file?

Comment: I have edited and attached the file to the end of the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using a *Mirror* modifier but your object is already symmetrical, so the artefacts we see are simply overlapping faces (faces of the original object + faces of the mirrored object). You need to either remove your *Mirror* modifier, or keep it but remove half of your topology.